# Кодирование русских символов для консоли разных операционных систем

Tags: java, консоль, кодировка, scanner

Всем привет, всем известная проблема с кодированием. Но как её грамотно решить для разных терминалов разных ОС ?

Например для вывода латинских символов, начало своей консольной программы я начинаю так

```
String consoleEncoding = System.getProperty("consoleEncoding");
if (consoleEncoding != null) {
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, consoleEncoding));
    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.err.println("Unsupported encoding set for console: "+consoleEncoding);
    }
}
```

но что делать с вводом ? если в консоли существует `Scanner`, который так же может принять русские символы?

Возможно ли аналогичным способом задавать кодировку и для сканера ? Спасибо

Comment: Латинские - имеется ввиду латинские символы помимо ascii?

Comment: @hardsky имеются ввиду русские символы. Важна поддержка именно их

Comment: Хм, в тексте вопроса вы спрашивате про енкодинг латинских символов

Comment: @hardsky исправил, дабы не вводить в заблуждение своим невежеством